# How can I return result of action after dispatching in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to use a result of action which was dispatched and dispatch new action.
There an example of code which I want to use

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        addApplication(data, vacancy_id) {
            dispatch(candidateActions.addCandidate(data))
                .then((newCandidate) => {
                          dispatch(applicationActions.addApplication(data.video, vacancy_id, newCandidate._id))
               });
        }
    }, dispatch);
}
```

How can I do this in redux and which libraries I can use?

Answer (score 4):

You should use a `thunk-middleware` which will be in charge of dispatching actions based on results of previous action. By using a thunk middleware, an action creator can return a function which is capable of dispatching its own actions.

lets say i have 3 actions:

```
1. loginRequest - send credentials for login
2. loginSuccess - dispatch action if credentials are valid
3. loginFailure - dispatch action if login failed
```

i can set up an function which does the below

```
    export function login(credentials){
      return function(dispatch){
        dispatch(loginRequest(credentials){
           return fetch(`http://localhost:8000/login`)
             .then(response => response.json())
              .then(json =>
                 dispatch(loginSuccess(creds))
             .catch(err => 
                 dispatch(loginFailure(err))
              })
            }
          }
```

You can then dispatch the login function from your component by including it in your `mapDispatchToProps`

You should probably check out - http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html for a better understanding